# AWS Lambda : read image from S3 upload event

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I am using Lambda to read image files when they are uploaded to S3 through a S3 trigger.  The following is my code:

```
import json
import numpy as np
import face_recognition as fr

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    for record in event['Records']:
        bucket=record['s3']['bucket']['name']
        key = record['s3']['object']['key']
        print(bucket,key)
```

This correctly prints the bucket name and key. However how do I read the image so that I can run face-recognition module on the image.  Can i generate the arn for each uploaded image and use it to read the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can read the image from S3 directly:

```py
s3 = boto3.client('s3')
resp = s3.get_object(Bucket=bucket, Key=key)
image_bytes = resp['Body'].read()
```